# Flutter - display local image from Camera

Tags: dart, flutter

I have generated an image using the [Flutter camera plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/camera). 
I am trying to display it.

My path looks like:

```
/data/user/0/com.example.myapp/app_flutter/picture2.jpg
```

How should I load it ?

I tried :

```
new Image.network("file:///"+imagePath)
```

but I get the error :

```
Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:////data/user/0/com.example.myapp/app_flutter/picture2.jpg
```

Comment: Use `Image.file(path}` instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835623/how-to-load-images-in-flutter-with-image-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way is to use :

```
new Image.file(File(imagePath))
```

see  [stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835623/how-to-load-images-in-flutter-with-image-file)

Answer (score 2):

Use FileImage like below. It takes the File as the parameter.

```
 _image = File(path);

Container(
               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
               color: Colors.white,
               image: DecorationImage(
                          image: FileImage(_image), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              )
```