# How to convert asset image to File?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to use an asset image as a File.
I need a File so it can be used for testing it over the internet using http. I've tried some answers from Stackoverflow.com ([How to load images with image.file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835623/how-to-load-images-with-image-file)) but get an error 'Cannot open file, (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)'. The attached code line also gives an error.

```
File f = File('images/myImage.jpg');

RaisedButton(
   onPressed: ()=> showDialog(
     context: context,
     builder: (_) => Container(child: Image.file(f),)),
   child: Text('Show Image'),)
```

Using Image.memory widget(works)

```
Future<Null> myGetByte() async {
    _byteData = await rootBundle.load('images/myImage.jpg');
  }

  /// called inside build function
  Future<File> fileByte = myGetByte();

 /// Show Image
 Container(child: fileByte != null
 ? Image.memory(_byteData.buffer.asUint8List(_byteData.offsetInBytes, _ 
 byteData.lengthInBytes))
 : Text('No Image File'))),
```

Comment: Use AssetBundle to read it into memory and store it to a file.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can access the *byte data* via [`rootBundle`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/AssetBundle-class.html). Then, you can save it to the device's temporary directory which is obtained by [`path_provider`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) (you need to add it as a dependency).

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
  final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');

  final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
  await file.create(recursive: true);
  await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

  return file;
}
```

In your example, you would call this function like this:

```
File f = await getImageFileFromAssets('images/myImage.jpg');
```

For more information on writing the byte data, [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50121777/6509751).

You will need to `await` the `Future` and in order to do that, make the function `async`:

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () async => showDialog(
     context: context,
     builder: (_) => Container(child: Image.file(await getImageFileFromAssets('images/myImage.jpg')))),
   child: Text('Show Image'));
```

Comment: I tested it and got an error: 'The argument type Future<File> can't be assigned to the parameter type File'. I've added test code above.

Comment: @AntD It is working correctly. You need to `await` the `Future` because it is an asynchronous request. To understand how `Future`'s work in Dart, you can read this guide: https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures

Comment: Thank you, but File f = await getImageFileFromAssets('images/myImage.jpg'); Gives 2 errors, unexpected text 'await' and Future file cannot be assigned to file. I'm using Android Studio, don't know how I'm getting the errors.

Comment: @AntD You should really check out the article I linked. I edited my answer to include the code you added.

Comment: @ creativecreatorormaybenot thank you very much, now it works after some experimenting, pasting the working code along above and thanks also to @ Günter Zöchbauer for mentioning to write to memory. Don't know about its efficiency of what I've done, if any thing to be cautious about please mention.

Comment: @ creativecreatorormaybenot thought I had the answer. But no, I can display File image from memory but I don't have a File for Image.File. Still trying to get it to work.

Comment: @ creativecreatorormaybenot now it really works. The problem I had was the function 'getImageFileFromAssets' was adding to it 'images/myImage.jpg' at getTemporaryDirectory(), instead of only '/myImage.jpg'. Finally I have a File! Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I follow the solution but I get the error about 
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.myApp/cache/images/black.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I think you should replace `final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');` with `final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/image.png');` it will save time for future commers

Comment: I added `await file.create(recursive: true);` after creating the file. Because if your path includes directories that does not exist yet, writing to that file fails because by default create is with recursive false.

Comment: @MustafaBerkayMutlu Thanks for pointing out it. You've saved my day!

Comment: getTemporaryDirectory() this function is not working now when I am using...

Comment: creativecreatorormaybenot, can you please edit your answer to include the line from @MustafaBerkayMutlu ?

Comment: To solve the `FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0...` error, just use this method instead: ```Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
  final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');
  final file = await File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path')
      .create(recursive: true);
  await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer
      .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
  return file;
}```

Answer (score 4):

Get File from Asset without providing a path.

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';


Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(Asset asset) async {
    final byteData = await asset.getByteData();

    final tempFile =
        File("${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/${asset.name}");
    final file = await tempFile.writeAsBytes(
      byteData.buffer
          .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes),
    );

    return file;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you asked me alongside the next [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65995#issuecomment-755071269). For people with problems with the image_picker in iOS 14.x

Comment: Asset class does not exist anywhere that I can find. Any insights?

Comment: The Asset class doesn't exist in your code as it is. For that matter you would need to install the multi_image_picker package and then to import it.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of flutter_absolute_path  package.

flutter_absolute_path: ^1.0.6

In pubsec.yaml

To convert file path from this format :

```
“content://media/external/images/media/5275”
```

To

```
"/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_00124.jpg”
```

======

```
List <File> fileImageArray = [];
assetArray.forEach((imageAsset) async {
final filePath = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(imageAsset.identifier);

File tempFile = File(filePath);
if (tempFile.existsSync()) {
    fileImageArray.add(tempFile);
}
```

Comment: you forget ")" in the last line edit it to make it easier for others