# Flutter convert image to binary data

Tags: flutter

How can i covert Image file to binary data ?
I'm using a library call  image_picker for pick the image from gallery or camera.
And I want to convert the image that I picked to binary data.

```
File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)
(image as Image).toByteData // the method toByteData here is not pop up.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[toByteData()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image/toByteData.html) method allows converting the `image` into a byte array. We need to pass the format in the format argument which specifies the format in which the bytes will be returned. It'll return the future that completes with binary data or error.

```
final pngByteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
```

`ImageByteFormat` enum contains the following constants.

- png
- rawRgba
- rawUnmodified
- values

For more information about `ImageByteFormat`, please have a look at this [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ImageByteFormat-class.html).

**Update :** If you want to convert the `image file` into bytes. Then use [readAsByte()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/readAsBytes.html) method.

```
var bytes = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery).readAsBytes();
```

For converting image into a file, Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55295810/4608334).

Comment: I tried to used the your method but toByteData didn't pop up.

Comment: Is your image in Image type or File type ? If it's in file type, then use readAsBytes method or it's in image type then use toByteData method. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Use readAsBytes() method without type casting to Image. It'll work

Comment: Try this var bytes = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery).readAsBytes();

Comment: Thanks alots I'll check it out.

Comment: I was trying to save an image with `File.writeAsBytes` and it was saving an invalid image file. Specifying `ImageByteFormat.png` is what was missing and now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

simply use this [method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/readAsBytes.html)

```
var bytes = await File('filename').readAsBytes();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using the `toByteData` method. 
It converts an image object into an array of bytes. 
It returns a future which returns a binary image data or an error if the encoding fails. 
Here is the implementation from this website: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image/toByteData.html

```
Future<ByteData> toByteData({ImageByteFormat format = ImageByteFormat.rawRgba}) {
  return _futurize((_Callback<ByteData> callback) {
    return _toByteData(format.index, (Uint8List encoded) {
      callback(encoded?.buffer?.asByteData());
    });
  });
}
```

The format argument specifies in which encoding format the bytes will be returned in.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_converter):

```
final pngBytes = image.pngUint8List;
```

or

```
final bmpBytes = image.bmpUint8List;
```