# How to download PDF file (Directly) from assets folder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, file, pdf, download

Screenshot of assets directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o62N4.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert asset image to File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295593/how-to-convert-asset-image-to-file)

Comment: @can It's just converting asset image to file, but how can i download that file ?

Comment: On top of that you could also check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966810/flutter-save-file-to-download-folder-downloads-path-provider

Get the file as bytes and save it to the specific path that you want. i.e. downloads

Answer (score -1):

try this instead

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

downloadFile(url) {
  html.AnchorElement(href: url)
  ..download = "your_file_name.pdf" // Specify the filename
  ..click();
}
```

Just make sure you pass correct url of your assets here.